# copy algorithm with back_inserter

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I do not understand why this code is accurate

```
vector<int> coll;
coll.reserve(2*coll.size());
copy (
  coll.begin(), coll.end(),    // zrodlo
  back_inserter(coll)          // przeznaczenie
);
```

`coll.end()` represents the end of vector. After I push_back anything (as `back_insert_iterator` does) what `coll.end()` returns is the same what was before or something different? Are there more than one terminating iterator? Why end() can be use as an end of container even when new content is added?

Moreover, you cannot apply the code to list container - it gets stuck. That is important because in case of vector push_back makes iterators unreliable after reallocating data (when `size()==capacity()` and `push_back()` called) whereas in case of list that's not the case. Than why the code hangs for list?

Edit: (sscce)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
inline void PRINT_ELEMENTS (const T& coll, const char* optcstr="")
{
    typename T::const_iterator pos;

    std::cout << optcstr;
    for (pos=coll.begin(); pos!=coll.end(); ++pos) {
        std::cout << *pos << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  list<int> coll;

  list<int>::iterator end = coll.end();
  copy (
    coll.begin(), coll.end(),    // zrodlo
    back_inserter(coll)          // przeznaczenie
    );
  cout << *end << endl;
  PRINT_ELEMENTS(coll);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `begin()` and `end()` pointers/iterators used to determine what is to be copied are evaluated once when the function is called. So essentially `std::copy()` will increment it's cursor iterator which will eventually reach `end()`, because `vector<T>::const_iterator` is just a fancy `T*` pointer on an old school array.

As you correctly mentionned, if a `push_back` makes the `vector` reallocate and move the data somewhere else in memory, then the next element copied will have a wrong address for source, which is likely to end up with a segmentaion fault.

For a list, it can never terminate because `end()` is a sentinel/guard pointer, and you can only reach `end()` by incrementing the iterator on the last element of the list. So the address of `end()` itself never changes, but because you are constantly adding an element at the end of the list, you will never reach the last element, so `std::copy()` can never obtain a pointer to `end()`. Kind of like a dog chasing it's tail.

It's easier to understand with illustrations and diagrams, read-up on doubly linked list and sentinel nodes, it will all make sense.

Answer (score 7):

`coll.end()` is called *before* the copying and back insertion begins, so essentially the code is the same as

```
coll.reserve(2*coll.size());
auto oldEnd = coll.end();
copy (coll.begin(), oldEnd, back_inserter(coll) );
```

meaning, `copy` will not re-evaluate `coll.end()`, so it will not notice/bother that it is inserting into the same vector, and that what once was the end of the vector is not the end after the first insertions.

The same algorithm will not *compile* for lists, because `std::list` has no `reserve` method. However, without `reserve` it should work for `list`s, since `std::list::push_back` does not invalidate iterators.
You are right that `std::vector::push_back` invalidates iterators when reallocation occurs, so it's very important to do the `reserve` call, because it makes sure no reallocation is needed.

Comment: I know there is no reserve() in list. I have tried the code for list. Programme gets into endless loop.

Comment: Can you show us an [SSCCE](http:/sscce.org) of the code you used to test that on list?